# variable project root folder in .dir-locals.el

Tags: projectile, company-mode, directory-local-variables

I'm using company-mode for completion in C++ code. To tell clang backend of company where the include files for the current project are I have to use the following `.dir-locals.el` file

```
((c++-mode (eval setq company-clang-arguments (append 
                                               company-clang-arguments
                                               '("-I/full/path/to/project/root/include"))))
```

I have to specify the full path always. Is there a way to replace `full/path/to/project/root` with a variable that stores the path the the `.dir-locals.el` file?

I tried

```
 (c++-mode (eval setq company-clang-arguments (append
                                               company-clang-arguments
                                               (list concat "-I" default-directory "src")))))
```

but since `default-directory` is evaluated in the file that I'm opening it doesn't return to path the the project root but some other path inside the project.

Comment: See also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26093/how-can-i-set-directory-local-variable-in-relative-to-dir-locals-el-file-locati

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution with [projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile). It has a function `projectile-project-root` which can be used to get the project path.

I can noe use the following in `.dir-locals.el` and it will still work when I move the project or use it on another machine.

```
((nil . ((eval . (progn
                   (require 'projectile)
                   (setq company-clang-arguments (delete-dups (append
                                                  company-clang-arguments
                                                  (list (concat "-I" (projectile-project-root) "src"))))))))))
```

Only downside is that it you need projectile and that the project has to be a projectile project (not much of a problem since every folder with git/bzr/hg/... is a valid project).

**update**

As pointed out in the comments it is also possible to use

`(locate-dominating-file default-directory ".dir-locals.el")`

instead of `projectile-project-root`.

Comment: `(locate-dominating-file default-directory ".dir-locals.el")` may also be an option, maybe even abbreviated into a function.

Comment: This is pretty much what `projectile-project-root` does. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: @politza: I don't think that works: it will pick up the closest `.dir-locals.el`, not the one that the form comes from.

Comment: I think that using `dir-locals-file` variable instead of ".dir-locals.el" string is more appropriate