# How can I set directory local variable in relative to .dir-locals.el file location?

Tags: directory-local-variables

I often find myself in the situation where I'm told to put absolute paths as directory local variable. For example [cmake-ide](https://github.com/atilaneves/cmake-ide#non-cmake-projects)'s `cmake-ide-project-dir` and `cmake-ide-build-dir`. Of course this is not very portable.

So instead of

**`.dir-locals.el`:**

```el
((nil . ((cmake-ide-project-dir . "/home/user/code/project"))))
```

I want something like

```el
((nil . ((cmake-ide-project-dir . directory-of-current-dir-locals-file))))
```

How can I define such a variable `directory-of-current-dir-locals-file`? And how would I set for example `cmake-ide-build-dir`, which is typically `(concat directory-of-current-dir-locals-file "build")`?

Answer (score 9):

My solution so far (based on [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012321/)):

**`.dir-locals.el`:**

```
;;; Directory Local Variables
;;; For more information see (info "(emacs) Directory Variables")

((nil . ((eval . (set (make-local-variable 'my-project-path)
                      (file-name-directory
                       (let ((d (dir-locals-find-file ".")))
                         (if (stringp d) d (car d))))))
         (cmake-ide-project-dir . my-project-path)
         (eval . (setq cmake-ide-build-dir (concat my-project-path "build")))
         )))
```

Comment: You can use also `(locate-dominating-file default-directory ".dir-local.el")`

Comment: @ibizaman It should be ".dir-local***s***.el": `(locate-dominating-file default-directory ".dir-locals.el")`

Answer (score -2):

You could define variable with `(defvar directory-of-current-dir-locals-file "/home/user/code/project")`.

Comment: Sorry maybe my question was not clear. But the idea was to **not** use absolute paths. Since you know you want to set the variable to something relative to the `.dir-locals.el` file.