# How can I use Flycheck on Perl code that installs its dependencies with Carton?

Tags: flycheck, perl

Perl module dependency manager [Carton](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carton) installs dependencies into a subdirectory of the project directory, and expects `perl` to be run under `carton exec` to set the necessary environment variables to locate the modules.  Flycheck runs plain `perl`, and consequently fails to find the correct modules, reporting an error for the missing module and masking any other problems.

How do I tell Flycheck where to look for these modules?

Answer (score 1):

Place the following in a file `.dir-locals.el` in the root of the project:

```
((perl-mode
  . ((eval
      . (let ((project-dir (expand-file-name
                            (locate-dominating-file default-directory
                                                    ".dir-locals.el"))))
          (setq-local flycheck-perl-include-path
                      (list (concat project-dir "lib")
                            (concat project-dir "local/lib/perl5/"))))))))
```

This is a special case of question [How can I set directory local variable in relative to .dir-locals.el file location?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26093/how-can-i-set-directory-local-variable-in-relative-to-dir-locals-el-file-locati).